# Load into div with JQuery - Div contains external

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page (index.php) that contains a div to dynamically load content:

```
<div id='#container'></div>
```

Into this div I am dynamically loading an external page using the following:

```
$(this).on('click', '.subNav', function () {
    var subSectionId = this.id;
    $("#content").load( 'pages/content.php?id=' + subSectionId );
});
```

The problem I have is this: On the page content.php there is a button (class .tblSort) that when clicked needs to reload content.php inside the div '#content'. I have the following JQuery code:

```
$(this).on('click', '.tblSort', function () { 
    var subSectionPageId = $("#subSectionId").val();
    var orderBy = this.id;
    $("#content").load( '/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + subSectionId + '&orderBy=' + orderBy );
});
```

It isn't working, and I assume this is due to the fact that the div '#content' is in the file index.php and the button (class .tblSort) is in the file content.php. What is the way around this?

Comment: `$(this).on...`? What is `this`? You're not specifying what you're clicking.

Comment: If the button is within content.php the you will need to attach the event listener to it again. Unless "this" is a delegate ..

Comment: @Jay Blanchard that code works. It is specified by the class '.subNav' ie. when any buttons on the page with the class .subNav the id is passed to the function.

Comment: .subNav is a class. Can you show us your button code? And can you show us the rest of the function?

Comment: <span class='subNav' id='id'>Button Name"</span>

Comment: check my answer below, replace $("#button).. with $(".subNav")...

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping your button click event in an ajax complete event.

I imagien you are defining the click event in a document ready and what is happening is that the jquery can not find the element your pointing it at initially.

try something like this..

```
//When all dom elements are ready on a page (images wont be loaded at this point)
$(document).ready(function(){

    //On click of the container, load the content from external source
    //Probably not clicking the container so change selector
    $("#container").on('click', function(){
        $("#content").load('pages/content.php?id=' + this.id);
    });

});

//.load() is an ajax call just wrapped up friendly, so attach an ajax complete event.
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

    //On the tblSort button click (dynamically loaded in #content above)
    $("#content .tblSort").on('click', function(){
        $("#content").load('/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + $("#subSectionId").val());
    });

});
```

Give that a try. Not tested so cant be sure it would work for you but i dont see why not.

**UPDATE**

Updating answer due to OP's comments.
Notice #container has changed to #button
@OP: update this selector to match your needs and extract the id as described.

```
//When all dom elements are ready on a page (images wont be loaded at this point)
$(document).ready(function(){

    //On click of the container, load the content from external source
    //Probably not clicking the container so change selector
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        $("#content").load('pages/content.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });

});

//.load() is an ajax call just wrapped up friendly, so attach an ajax complete event.
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

    //On the tblSort button click (dynamically loaded in #content above)
    $("#content .tblSort").on('click', function(){
        $("#content").load('/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + $("#subSectionId").val());
    });

});
```

Comment: The problem is that we don't even know what the OP is asking at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of this you can use body or the parent div element which is not change on run time.

```
$('body').on('click', '.tblSort', function () { 
    var subSectionPageId = $("#subSectionId").val();
    $("#content").load( '/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + subSectionId );
});
```

Comment: but with this code I wouldn't be passing the id of the button to the function? The code I posted was actually simplified. I need to get the ID of the button clicked. I've edited the post.

Comment: alert($(this).attr('id')); Try that in the click event, see if you get the right id, if so just add it in and pass it

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work,

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        //On the tblSort button click (dynamically loaded in #content above)
        $("#content").on('click','.tblSort', function(){
            $("#content").load('/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + $(this).parent().val());
        });

    });
```

OR

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    //On the tblSort button click (dynamically loaded in #content above)
    $("#content").on('click','.tblSort', function(){
        $("#content").load('/pos2/pages/content.php?id=' + $(this).parent().find("#subSectionId").val());
    });

});
```

If you are unable to run then share your exact code and explain